# How to randomly select images and put them to multiple folders in Python

Tags: python

I have a directory with following images, and I want to randomly select 3 images and put them in multiple folders say: folder 1, 2, and 3 etc. How can i do it in Python? Thanks.

[image]

I have tried so far:

```
import os, random
import shutil 
import glob


folder = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Image"
a=random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
print(a)

src_dir = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Image"
dst_dir = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Image/1"
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
    shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Not move, but copy randomly selected images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
import random

to_be_moved = random.sample(glob.glob("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Image/*.jpg"), 3):

for f in enumerate(to_be_moved, 1):
    dest = os.path.join("C:/Users/User/Desktop", str(f[0]))
    if not os.path.exists(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest)
    shutil.copy(f[1], dest)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry i'm new in Python. Just another questions: what if i hope to randomly select 3 images instead of 1 and put them in each of folders created? and what if the folder name if a string instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
import os, random
import shutil

m = 3
n = 3

src_dir = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/source/"
dst_dir = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/destination/"

file_list = os.listdir(src_dir)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        a = random.choice(file_list)
        #file_list.remove(a)
        shutil.copy(src_dir + a, dst_dir + str(i+1) + "/" + a)
```